# Can I have the same stored procedure with two different name?

Tags: sql, database, azure

Bellow, I have a stored procedure named **usp_customer**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_customer 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER       
END
```

I want to give the same exact stored procedure a second name **usp_cust1**

Note: I am not looking to rename or to create a new stored procedure, I want both names to work

In the end, I could use either `EXEC usp_customer`   or `EXEC usp_cust1`

Thanks

edit: changed sp_ to usp_

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

One stored procedure can call another:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_cust1
AS 
BEGIN 
    EXEC usp_customer;    
END;
```

Note that in SQL Server, you should not use the "sp_" prefix for stored procedures.  That is best reserved only for system stored procedures.

Comment: is there any way I could do that without creating a new procedure?

Comment: No.  If you want two stored procedures you have to create them . . . or a synonym would also work.